# ¿Cómo funciona realmente fscanf en estos dos casos?

Tags: c

Son dos mis dudas acerca del comportamiento de **fscanf** y las resumiré en los siguientes dos casos.

**CASO 1**

Imaginad que tenéis el **archivo de texto *ejemplo.txt*** con el siguiente contenido: 12.3 13.4 14.5 5.5

Dado el siguiente **código**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        FILE *f; float ft;
        f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        while(!feof(f)){
                fscanf(f,"%f",&ft);
                printf("%f\n", ft);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Ejecutamos el **comando** "./programa ejemplo.txt".

¿Por qué la salida siempre repite **el último número dos veces**? ¿No debería haber avanzado el puntero f al final del fichero tras la primera lectura de 5.5 y haber salido del bucle después?

**CASO 2**

Supongamos exactamente la **misma situación**, pero el contenido de *ejemplo.txt* es ahora el siguiente: 12.3 13.4 14.5 **hola** 5.5

¿Por qué imprime en un **bucle infinito 14.5**? Al encontrar una estructura no esperada (pues espera un float, no un String), ¿por qué reacciona así?

Gracias, esto es todo.

Comment: [`feof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) retorna verdadero despues de que la anterior lectura se tope con el final del archivo (Mira la nota en la documentacion). Entonces se lee el ultimo numero, lo imprimes, `feof` retorna falso ya que la ultima lectura no reporto nada, y luego al tratar de leer te topas con que ya no hay nada que leer. Entonces no se modifica `ft`, lo imprimes, y como ahora si te topaste con el final, `feof` retonra verdadero y terminas el ciclo. Por eso `feof` no es la forma correcta de verificar si ya terminaste de leer el archivo.

Comment: Y para el segundo caso. Que esperas que pase si le das un string cuando espera un `float`? Lo que hace es: no modifica la variable, ni sacara nada de `stdin`, y retorna que no leyo nada (Puedes hacer `int algo = scanf(...)`, y `algo` guardara la cantidad de cosas que se leyeron). Pero como el error con el que te topas no es que hayas llegado al final del archivo, lo del loop volvera a correr, pero como `hola` sigue estando en el stream, te toparas con ese error infinitamente.

Comment: La solucion a ambos problemas es simple, revisa el valor que te retorna `fscanf` para saber si lograste leer correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por su explicación, la entendí perfectamente. Entonces, ¿cuál sería la manera adecuada de manejar el fin de fichero? ¿Alguna función en concreto?

Comment: Revisa el valor que te retorna `fscanf`. Si no lograste leer, puedes ver con `feof` si se termino el archivo, o si no es eso, puedes tener cierta certeza de que el formato del archivo es incorrecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feof()` no es True hasta que no haya ocurrido una operación de lectura que haya encontrado el final del fichero. `fscanf()` ha leido el 5.5 con éxito, por lo que no reporta fin de fichero. El siguiente `fscanf()` ya no podrá leer otro flotante, pues encontrará el fin de fichero y retornará error (en este caso no se modifica `ft`, que sigue valiendo 5.5 de la iteración anterior). Entonces `feof()` ya será True y el bucle terminará.

En el segundo caso al encontrarse "hola", de nuevo `fscanf()` retornará un error y dejará sin tocar la variable `ft`. Debido al error tampoco avanza el puntero de lectura del fichero, por lo que en la siguiente iteración estará en las mismas, volverá a producir un error, etc...

Tu fallo está en no verificar si `fscanf()` te está retornando o no un error. Eso debes verificarlo recogiendo el valor retornado, que es el número de items correctamente leidos y almacenados por `fscanf()`. Debería ser mayor de cero.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        FILE *f; float ft;
        int ok;
        f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        while(!feof(f)){
                ok = fscanf(f,"%f",&ft);
                if (ok <= 0) {
                   printf("No se encuentran datos válidos para fscannf()");
                   break;
                }
                printf("%f\n", ft);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Ahora ante un error escribimos un mensaje de error, y salimos del bucle.